# How to do sudo grep in a bash script?

Tags: debian, bash, grep

I would like to check if the given ip address is already in the config file.
But /etc/ can only be accessed by root, and I'm running the a script as admin.
It seems I can't just do sudo

```
#!/bin/bash
CLIENT_WG_IPV4="10.66.66.1"

DOT_EXISTS=$(sudo grep -c "$CLIENT_WG_IPV4/22" "/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf")
if [[ ${DOT_EXISTS} == '0' ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

I get the error message:

> grep: /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf: Permission denied

What can I do?

Comment: sudo is certainly asking for a password. you should run your script as an authorized user or as root without sudo.